# action do <p:comandbutton> em JSF não é invocada para download

Tags: java, jsf

Bom dia pessoal, preciso abrir um dialog para relatório, e no p:inputtext preciso validar se existe esse cliente , se não existir abro uma lista de cliente por outro dialog e seleciona qual cliente,porem preciso fazer um download do relatório quando abro esse dialog não e clico no botão de gerar o relatório não acontece o download pois o Ajax vira true e fecha o dialog do relatório, quando abro novamente os dados continuam e consigo fazer o download. gostaria de saber como fazer o Ajax ficar false novamente para não fechar a tela e fazer o download estou utilizando o primefaces e apache poi.

segue o código

```xml
    <p:inputText id="cliente" value="#{dialogpadrao.cliente}" autocomplete="off" size="10">
        <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{dialogpadrao.abredialogcliente}" update="cliente descrição" />
    </p:inputText>

    <p:outputLabel id="descrição" value="#{dialogpadrao.desccli}" />

</h:panelGrid>
```

```java
public void abredialogcliente() {
        Cadcli clientep = new Cadcli();

        if (cliente != null && !cliente.isEmpty()) {
            clientep = new Cadcli();
            EntityManager manager = this.getManager();
            CadcliRepository repository = new CadcliRepository(manager);
            clientep = repository.procuracodigo(cliente);
            if (clientep.getId() == null) {
                session.setAttribute("pagina", "dialogpadrao");
                org.primefaces.context.DefaultRequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dlgcliente').show()");
            } else {
                    cliente = clientep.getCodcli();
                    this.setDesccli(clientep.getDesccli());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Poste a página completa. Você debugou pra ver se está chegando no seu método? Checou o id de `dlgcliente` para confirmar se está correto na página?

Answer (score 0):

Bom pessoal ja resolvi o problema , para quem passar pelo mesmo problema so tirei o session.setAttribute("pagina", "dialogpadrao"); e coloquei o valor direto da variável e
 assim funcionou.